# FitNesse for Delphi 2006 / Delphi 2007 /Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, fitnesse, fit-framework

Is there a version of FitNesse that works on Delphi 2006/2007/2009?

If so where can I find It?

Are there any other programs like FitNesse that work on Delphi 2006?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fitnesse has support for Delphi.  See the [FitServers](http://www.fitnesse.org/FrontPage.FitServers) page at fitnesse.org.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

The Delphi fit server at [delphixtreme](http://delphixtreme.com/wordpress/?page_id=4) **now works**

The code is saved [here](http://code.google.com/p/fit4delphi/)

Comment: You should probably edit your question and give details about the problems you are having with those FitServers.

Comment: Yes, "does not work" does not tell us what is wrong.  Do they give you an error message?  Do they catch on fire?  Do they behave incorrectly?  Do they raid the fridge?