# Delphi and Fitnesse/fit4delphi examples?

Tags: delphi, fitnesse

Is there any opensource or example projects showing the use of fitnesse with delphi?

It's sad how hard it is to find resources and information for delphi... :-/

**UPDATE:**
Ok. I realize that my question was a little short. Searching SO and google was kind of obvious for me, so I didn't mention that I already did. So to clarify a little:
* I know about fit4delphi (thereof the use of fit4delphi both in the title and the taglist)
* I know fit4delphi is somewhat maintained (both from fit4delphi site and other SO-thread)
* I know the most basic examples from fitnesse is ported to delphi and comes with fit4delphi
* I know it is possible to use delphi together with fit/fitnesse (comes from the knowledge of fit4delphi and basic google search giving lots of results stating that it is possible)

What I want, is examples of use, not a google query showing that it is possible to use.
I want stories by people with experience from fit4delphi, not from people with experiences from basic google querying.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a simple google on "fitnesse delphi" I came up with a few different results.

You might want to look at this for starters:

[Fitnesse for Delphi 2006 / Delphi 2007 /Delphi 2009 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91826/fitnesse-for-delphi-2006-delphi-2007-delphi-2009)

Or maybe you want to try the google query I used:

[Google for "fitnesse delphi"](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&num=20&newwindow=1&q=fitnesse+delphi&meta=lr%3Dlang_en|lang_de&fp=3a5dc1e28da675ae)

I don't know much about fitnesse but I didn't find it difficult to find information about it WRT Delphi.

Ryan.

Comment: Yes, I have googled, and I have found the other delphi/fit-SO thread. I know about fit4delphi, and I know about google. What I want, is examples of use. Did you find any examples of use with your google query, or did you just find a lot of references to fitnesse and some stating that it is possible to do fit with delphi?

Comment: Following the first few links of the Google query results generally lead you to either the Delphi Fitnesse project (DelphiFIT) or to delphiextreme crowd and fit4delphi.  Both have code and seem to have active development.  

If your looking for a forum with activity then try this: 

http://www.delphixtreme.com/forums/ 

or maybe this: 

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/fitnesse/

Both of these appear to be active groups.

Comment: @TOndrej:  I laughed hard at your link.  I haven't seen that before.  Thanks.

Comment: Ryan: Have you any experience with delphi and Fitnesse? Other than googling? If so, could you please answer the question instead of showing of your google-fu?